# Inconsistent Axios 401 Error On React Native

Tags: react-native, cookies, axios, expo, credentials

So I want to connect my react native app with the backend using cookies, I tested to do so from NodeJS, and its working, I can retrieve the data. The code is like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PH4J.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFkbD.png)

So now I tested to run on RN, initially, I am able to access it, but later, when i try to access again, i got 401 error and that problem persists UNTIL I clear all the app storage. Your help is really appreciated.

Just a bit background, at first I though its expo problem, so i created the new app using react-native, but now both got the same issue. and one thing for sure it is not related to invalid cookie since I can still use it from my NodeJS

Any potentially remedies that i can possibly apply